# How do I not ignore the "id" attribute in insert / update requests?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I would like to update a specific id attribute with "updateAll" method. Its possible?

```
Model.updateAll({userId:10}, {userId:5, name:'test'}, function (...
```

"UserId" is id attribute in model.json

sql syntax

```
update table set name='test' where userId=10
```

Why its not possible to update userId like so?

```
update table set name='test' and userId=5 where userId=10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in loopback way because of [this line](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector/blob/master/lib/sql.js#L1254).

Loopback excludes the `id`s from insert/update fileds.

But you can do it like :

```
app.datasources.mysql.connector.execute('update table set name=? , 
  userId=? where userId=?', ['test', 5, 10], function(err, result){...
```

**UPDATE**

Even loopback doesn't allow to update model id through `updateAttribute(s)` method. [this line](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/dao.js#L3128)

Comment: Thanks @Ebrahim Pasbani, but i dont want to use sql syntax. i need to use loopback method independent from the data source connector.

Comment: @J.Doe As I mentioned and addressed in the answer, loopback prevents to set model id through any update operations